# Jmeter Multiple request using non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I want to run 1500 request same time from non-GUI mode.

Currently, I am using the following command to run a single request.
jmeter -n –t Anilwebsite.jmx -l testresults.jtl.

Please help me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a single request at exactly the same moment apply the following configuration:

- [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - Number of threads - `1500`

  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

    - [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) - Number of simulated users to group by - `1500`

This way you will get guarantee that all 1500 requests will be fired exactly at the same moment.

Comment: Thanks, @Dmitri T. Do I need to add the number of request in Threadgroup? will it work ?

Comment: I am using the following request for same:
jmeter -Jthreads=1500 -n -tAnilwebsite.jmx -l result.jtl. But it is only showing a single request after run.

Comment: Change `Number of threads` in the Thread Group from whatever it is there to use [__P() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) like `${__P(threads)}`